# Order Notification mail in prestashop 1.4

Tags: email, prestashop

I am using prestashop 1.4 .

When user order something they [customer] get order confirmation email.

But admin don't get notification for that order.

So i plan to add a custom e-mail , can you help me to locate the file.

Or if there is any another option ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it by using prestashop built in module called **Mail Alerts** . Install this module, and check new order checkbox only. After that below the page, enter all the admin emails you want to send the email for new order.

This module has some other options also.

Thank you

Comment: do you know which file has that mail function?

Answer (score 1):

you should get a new order confirmation in back office top left, you may need to refresh the page. like altafhussain said you can set up mail alerts.

i believe you can also get an order confirmation email to automatically print which is ideal for picking orders in good time.

Answer (score 1):

Other idea is to use and external program like automatic email manager to print your order automatically, it supports also print attachment (useful to print receipt)
http://www.automatic-email-manager.com/